# uhttpd & PHP access files on sd card

Tags: php, openwrt

I'm trying to make my php filemanager to be able to manage files outside the web-root. I'm using a router with OpenWRT. I have PHP5 and uhttpd (default Luci webserver) installed. The files are stored on a USB drive that's not always plugged in. The index.php is located in /www and the files are stored (when mounted) in /mnt/sda1.
I've been playing around with the permissions and user/groups with nog success.

Is there a way to do this? I don't want the filemanager itself running from the USB drive.

Answer (score 0):

It seemingly isn't possible without a second webserver (different port) so I'm going to use a samba server that directs to a symlink to the /mnt/sda1 and use php to access the samba server.